# how to navigate between fields of Editform with Enter key in Blazor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I want to navigate between fields of Editform with Enter Key thats means i want Enter Key act as Tab key using c# code in blazor,
I use this code but it does not work

```
<EditForm Model="@productDtoVM" OnValidSubmit="Save">
      <InputText @bind-Value="productDtoVM.itmNo" class="form-control"@onkpress="Tab"/>
</EditForm>
```

this is Tab method

```
 void Tab(KeyboardEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Key == "Enter")
            {
                e.Key = "Tab";
            }
        }
```

i tried to use @onkeyup and @onkeydown instead of @onkeypress but they not working

Comment: Your code will not work because in the browser DOM the key code is readonly, i.e., it will not allow you to map the enter key to the tab key.  There other ways to make this work, like setting the focus on the next input element, but the solutions are not simple.

Comment: Hello Haneen was the answer helpful? Do you still need any assistance on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this functionality with this setup, you can use tabIndex to find next control to move to with enter key press

```
<EditForm id="my-form" Model="@product" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmNo" tabindex=0 @bind-Value="@product.ItmNo" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item No" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmName" tabindex=1 @bind-Value="@product.ItmName" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmDescription" tabindex=2 @bind-Value="@product.ItmDescription" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item Description" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label></label><br />
</EditForm>


@code {

    private productDtoVM product = new();    
    
    public void keydown(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs args)
    {        
       if (args.Key == "Enter")
       {
          JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("moveFocus");
      }
    }

    public class productDtoVM
    {
        public string ItmNo { get; set; }
        public string ItmName { get; set; }
        public string ItmDescription { get; set; }
    }
}
```

This is javascript function which moves focus to next control

```
function moveFocus() {
    var ele = document.activeElement;
    var tabIndex = ele.tabIndex;

    var inputs = document.getElementById("my-form").elements;

    for (i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
        if (inputs[i].tabIndex > tabIndex)
        {
            inputs[i].focus();
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Let me know your thoughts on it

Answer (score 0):

***`"I tried to use @onkeyup and @onkeydown instead of @onkeypress but they not working"`***

> No you won't be able to get the activity like that way, We can achieve the same thing with help of calling the focus() method in the JS interop on keydown event handler.
> Please try below way:

***`Edit Form:`***

```
@page "/"
@using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations


<EditForm Model="@product" OnValidSubmit="@HandleValidSubmit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />
 
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmNo" @bind-Value="@product.ItmNo" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item No" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmName" @bind-Value="@product.ItmName" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <InputText id="ItmDescription" @bind-Value="@product.ItmDescription" @onkeydown="@keydown" placeholder="Item Description" />
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Register</button>
    <br />
    <br />
    <label> @KeyPressed</label><br />
</EditForm>
```

***`C# Code:`***

```
@code{
string KeyPressed = "";

public productDtoVM product = new productDtoVM();

[Inject]
protected IJSRuntime JsRuntime { get; set; }

public async Task HandleValidSubmit()
{
}
public class productDtoVM
{
    public string ItmNo { get; set; }
    public string ItmName { get; set; }
    public string ItmDescription { get; set; }
}

public void keydown(Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Web.KeyboardEventArgs args)
{
    KeyPressed = "Key Pressed is " + args.Key;
    if (args.Key == "Enter")
    {
        JsRuntime.InvokeVoidAsync("onFocus", "ItmNo");
    }
}
```

}

***`JavaScript Code On wwwroot`:***

```
window.onFocus = (id) => {
    var currInput = document.activeElement;
    if (currInput.tagName.toLowerCase() == "input") {
        var inputs = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
        var currInput = document.activeElement;
        for (var i = 0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
            if (inputs[i] == currInput) {
                var next = inputs[i + 1];
                if (next && next.focus) {
                    next.focus();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

> **Note:** Javascript code should be under below directory:

[image]

***`Output:`***

[image]

> **Note:** This just for a quick demo example so that you would perceive how to deal with the `event handeler` in `edit form`

Hope above steps guided you accordingly.

Comment: If you think it was useful you could accept the answer you can do that by right clicking on left check mark beside your question [you could have a look here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86978/how-do-i-accept-an-answer-on-stackoverflow)
[How to accept answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)