# Blazor - If Enter key pressed, else accept input as normal

Tags: c#, .net, input, blazor

I want to be able to handle input on an input field in blazor.
If the key is enter, it needs to move to the next field. Else, it needs to handle input like nothing else has changed.
Currently, the input is as follows:

```
<input type="number" @bind="CurrentValueAsString" @onkeypress="@KeyPress" @onkeypress:preventDefault />
```

Here is the function:

```
public void KeyPress(KeyboardEventArgs e)
{
   if(e.Code == "Enter")
   {
      TryParseValueFromString(Value, out T Result, out string ValidationMsg);
   }
}
```

I've tried removing the @onkeypress:preventDefault, but this doesn't allow the KeyPress function to run. Not sure where else to look with this

Comment: This question seems answered here  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634858/how-to-navigate-between-fields-of-editform-with-enter-key-in-blazor/71659765#71659765

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to navigate between fields of Editform with Enter key in Blazor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71634858/how-to-navigate-between-fields-of-editform-with-enter-key-in-blazor)

Comment: Thanks, but no, the post doesn't solve the issue. I need to be able to move away when the Enter key is pressed, but if normal keys are entered, the input should accept the input as normal

Comment: Are you able to reach the `KeyPress` method by typing something in the input?

Comment: Change OS default behaviour is not a good idea. You should to take in mind accessibility and this looks like an anti-pattern.